# How can I have development and production versions of robots.txt on Google App Engine (PHP)?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, robots.txt

I have a website/app that can operate in a standard web hosting environment and on the Google App Engine. So I develop on Cloud9, deploy test versions (via GitHub) to an appspot.com URL, and ultimately to the GAE project that's associated with the custom domain.

I wanted web crawlers to be entirely disallowed on the development sites and to have specified access on the production site. But I didn't want to have the task of managing different versions of a robot.txt file.

What I developed is posted as an answer below. Perhaps it will be helpful to others or perhaps someone has a more elegant solution.

p.s. I read up on the most appropriate etiquette for someone asking and immediately answering their own question. There was a difference of opinion primarily divided between those who believed the answer should remain in the question (so as not to appear as if one was trying to increase their own reputation) versus posting an official answer. I'm choosing the latter based on the logic that if a person is looking for an answer and sees a posting with 0 answers, they won't know that there might be a solution they could consider.

Comment: Just be aware that crawlers might chose to ignore the `robots.txt` file, so don't use it as an access control measure.

Comment: @Dan: Good to know. Thank you. My primary motivation for creating the robots.txt file was that I was tired of seeing errors about it missing in the GAE log. Once I went through the effort, I figured I might as well list files I preferred not be seen. Nevertheless, I'm glad you mentioned what you did.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to have PHP generate a response.

Since I have no other reason to serve text files, app.yaml file is modified so that a request to any .txt extension triggers the primary script (which is included by index.php)...

```
- url: /(.*\.(txt$))
  script: index.php
```

The PHP script parses the URL...

```
$argument = basename(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH));
if ($argument !== "" && $argument !== "index.php") {
    if ($argument == "robots.txt") {
        $action = "answerRobot";
    }
    elseif ($argument == "_________") {
        // Other things I look for such as translating directory
        // requests into actions. For instance website.com/admin 
        // (a non-existent directory) triggers an admin function 
        // in the main script. 
    }
}
```

I then check to see what environment I'm in — first whether I'm running in GAE and then which project...

```
if (strpos(getcwd(), "/base/data/home/apps/s~____") > -1) {
    $appEngine = true;

    if (strpos($_SERVER["APPLICATION_ID"], "dev") > -1) {
        $crawlable = false;
    }
    else {
        $crawlable = true;
    }
}
```

Finally, I generate robots.txt content if required...

```
if ($action == "answerRobot") {
    header("Content-type: text/plain");

    if ($crawlable) {
        $content = "User-agent: *"
            . "\nDisallow: /code/"
            . "\nDisallow: /icons/"
            . "\nDisallow: /specific_file.ext"
            . "\nDisallow: /specific_file.ext"
        ;
    }
    else {
        $content = "User-agent: *"
            . "\nDisallow: /"
        ;
    }
    echo $content;
    exit();
}
```